# Java - How to create a subprocess in a class that is running a method

Tags: java, sockets, multiprocessing, udp, robotics

I'm writing a program that enables UDP communication between a KUKA robot (programmed in java) and a python server running on a PC. The program on the robot needs to run multiple methods concurrently because it needs to listen/receive messages on 3 sockets simultaneously (they all need to be listening for messages at all times).

I first tried this using multi-threading. My main class is DP_UDP_COMM which start running when the robot is started. When starting some initialization between the robot and python server is done to set up the socket connection, after that the communication processes need to be started. An example of 1 of these 'communication' threads is shown below as Thread UDP_COMM:

```
//DP_UDP_COMM class is the main class that gets started when the robot starts
public class DP_UDP_COMM extends RoboticsAPITask {

//Some code here

    //One of the communication processes that needs to run while the DP_UDP_COMM instance is active
    public Thread UDP_COMM = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            while(running){
                 _log.info("Thread Started, Waiting for Action");
        
                try {
                    ReceiveUDP();
                    _log.info("Buffer received is: "+String.valueOf(receive));
                    _log.info("Type received is: "+String.valueOf(ByteProcess.getType(receive)));
                    if(status==0)
                        processPacket(receive);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    send = createPacketResponse("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
                    try {
                        SendUDP(send);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();                   }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                       
            }
        }
    });

    UDP_COMM.start();   

//Some code and other methods here

}
```

This thread tries to receive a UDP message from a socket using ReceiveUDP(). This is a blocking method so it keeps waiting here untill it receives a message. This message is then processed using processPacket(), which is a method that sends a command to the robot determined by the message that was received. After sending the command it starts listening again for new messages. This loops indefinitely when the robot is active.

The other threads are very similar but use slightly different methods which are bound to different sockets.(For example ReceiveUDPEmergency() which is the same as ReceiveUDP() but with a different socket)

This is working well with one thread, but when running 3 threads concurrently it doesn't work anymore because the threads will wait for each other to complete before looping because ReceiveUDP() is a blocking method.

The solution for this (I think) is to use multi-processing instead of multi-threading because this truly runs them in parallel instead of sequentially.
However when looking at the java.lang.Process documentation I really don't get how creating a process works. In every example they create/start a process from an external .exe file or something like that.

Is it possible to create multiple processes that run multiple methods in parallel within my DP_UDP_COMM instance? How would I do this?

//What have I tried:
As explained above I tried multi-threading at first. But this isn't good enough.

With multi-processing it is not clear how to start a process which just runs a method in parallel to the main instance.

Comment: "Blocking" is not the same as "synchronized". "Blocking" means that the current thread has to wait, but all other threads are still running. It is therefore unclear where your problem is.

Comment: It is not "because ReceiveUDP is a blocking method"